# Azure Batch Service showing more tasks running per node than configuration should allow

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I am running with this configuration:

- 1 Pool
- 2 VMs (8 cores)
- 1 Job
- 200 Tasks
- 32 Tasks per Node (what I expected to be max.)

However, I am seeing on summary in the Job overview blade that I am running more than 64 tasks. I have seen numbers ranging 64-84.

Am I missing some piece of configuration? Shouldn't  this be impossible without a service request?

Thanks

Comment: Hiya Anna, `:)` I thought I will ask few more question to understand this better: can you please mention, i.e. what is the scenario and what correlation in particular is confusing i.e. is it something UI based are you seeing? i.e. =>  Without any trigger are you seeing some UI issue? or is it task to the number of cores relations which is in question here? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tats_innit, I did see these numbers via the UI but I assumed the UI was showing what was really happening. The UI didn't seem buggy. The Tasks per core max + number of VMs didn't match with my expected max number of tasks "running" at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft provided the answer to this:

Apparently tasks show as "running" when they are "preparing" or if they're actually "running." Preparing means they have been assigned to a node and they're ready to run.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-get-task-counts